# How to move tablespace to another directory?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Let's say I have tablespace `A` located in the directory `/A1`, and I would like to move it (everything) to directory `/A2`?

I use openSUSE + PostgreSQL 9.1, and if this simplifies anything -- I can stop it (entire server) without a problem. Please note I am asking about entire tablespace and the tablespace already contains data!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This excerpt from the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) should get you going:

> The directory $PGDATA/pg_tblspc contains symbolic links that point to each of the non-built-in tablespaces defined in the cluster. Although not recommended, it is possible to adjust the tablespace layout by hand by redefining these links. Two warnings: do not do so while the server is running; and after you restart the server, update the pg_tablespace catalog with the new locations. (If you do not, pg_dump will continue to output the old tablespace locations.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, and it is fast. For the record `pg_tablespace` is a table in Postgresql catalog.

Comment: Seems PostgreSQL 9.2 removed the reference to a path in `pg_tablespace`.